# Respecter et admirer

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

J'ai entendu quelqu'un dire :

> Je ne respecte personne.

Est-ce possible que la tournure signifie

> Je n'admire personne.

Y a-t-il un changement sémantique ?

Comment: *'[...] il **n'a pas** voulu dire qu'il **n'a pas** de respect pour **aucune** personne[...]* : triple négation difficile à comprendre...

Comment: @jlliagre Tu as raison. Je l'ai effacée entiérement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Ne pas respecter* est beaucoup plus fort que *Ne pas admirer*.

Cependant la tournure *ne pas respecter* s'utilise habituellement plutôt pour parler d'un règle, une loi, une consigne.

Si on parle d'une personne, on pourra dira *ne pas avoir de respect pour* ou, plus idiomatique mais de sens différent : *manquer de respect à quelqu'un* (c'est à dire par ex. : insulter, parler mal, bousculer, mais pas juste *penser du  mal de quelqu'un*).

Il existe une palette de nuance pour indiquer le niveau de défiance envers des personnes (du plus faible au plus fort) :

> - Je n'idolatre personne / Je ne vénère personne.
> - Je n'admire personne.
> - Je n'ai pas d'estime pour eux.
> - Je n'ai de respect pour personne parmi eux / Je n'ai pas de respect
>   pour eux.
> - Je méprise ces gens / Je n'ai que du mépris pour eux.